# Camel ErrorHandler not invoking

Tags: apache-camel

I'm calling out to a WS using cxf:cxfEndpoint and its working fine. I want to catch any exceptions using onException or something similar. For some reason its not working. I have set the dataFormat to PAYLOAD, handleFault attribute on the route and/or the camel context to true. The web service is not running so I'm expecting the exception to be caught but its not working. Same issue with unmarshalling of the XML.

When I throw an exception using  it gets caught successfully using java.lang.Exception and written to my dummy exception queue... but when the webservice is down or I pass in some invalid XML and the marshalling fails then an exception gets thrown but not caught.

Is there anything else to be aware of?

EDIT: Included the code for unmarshaling. Switched to using Try/Catch and when i pass in invalid XML the exception does get caught during the junit testing but does not get caught at runtime

```
    <route>
        <from uri="jmsamq:In"/>
        <doTry>
            <unmarshal>
                <jaxb contextPath="outbound.message"/>
            </unmarshal>
            <doCatch>
                <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                <handled>
                    <constant>true</constant>
                </handled>
                <transform>
                    <simple>Mapping Failed</simple>
                </transform>
                <to uri="jmsamq:errorqueue1"/>
            </doCatch>
        </doTry>
        <log message="${body}"/>
        <multicast stopOnException="true">
            <to uri="direct:webservice"/>
            <to uri="direct:myqueue"/>
        </multicast>
    </route>
```

Comment: I use doTry / doCatch (http://camel.apache.org/try-catch-finally.html) for web services, creating a fault message and setting the response code. Next to that - when you use invalid XML, the parsing will fail at the CXF endpoint and the route doesn't even get involved.

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see what you are doing?

Comment: doTry / doCatch worked for the web service - thanks! It doesn't help with the unmarshalling to jaxb though.. should that be wrapped in a doTry block as well? I'm sure it will work, but is that necessary? Do you know why the onException would not work with web services? Something to do with the fact that a Fault is getting thrown rather than an exception maybe?

Comment: actually the try catch is only working with my junit.. when I run on the server it still isn't working

Answer (score 0):

the incorrect camel-context XML file was being used at runtime.. ignore question!